# Google Sheet query SELECT double character columns like AA,AB

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Hello everyone I need help with the following query:

```
=query(CRM!$A$2:$U$160;"select L,B,C,D,G,E,AA,AB,AC,AD where L matches '1. Working' OR L matches '3. Main Contact'";0)
```

It should just give me all the information I want from the sheet CRM where the Status is 1. Working or 3. Main Contact.
That also worked as long as I selected columns which where single character but once I wanted information out of column AA and beyond it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: AA
```

when I remove AA, it gives me the same error message just for AB, AC etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range of your query is `CRM!$A$2:$U$160`, so in order to select col AA, you need to extend the range to include it:

`CRM!$A$2:$AA$160`